# MissingResourceException , can't find bundle for basename, locale en-us in quarkus native image

Tags: resourcebundle, quarkus-native

I have a basename.properties file in resources folder. Whenever I try to load a bundle using

```
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(resourceBundlePath));
        URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(VALIDATION_MESSAGES, locale, loade);
```

in dev mode, resourceBundle variable is fetching corresponding locale file and if not present, it picks the default basename.properties file without throwing any exception. But, in GraalVM native image, it throws Missing resource exception, Can't find bundle for base name and locale en-us.

If the locale doesn't exist in the external classloader, it is not performing fallback to just basename.properties file. Could someone help?